# Need fix for Xgboost compilation error on CentOS7 R

Tags: r, centos, g++, xgboost

While i'm trying to install xgboost package i am running into this error. I have performed these steps to update my GCC still the problem persists

yum install devtoolset-7

scl enable devtoolset-7 bash

gcc --version

```
gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
trying URL 'https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/CRAN/src/contrib/xgboost_1.4.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 988320 bytes (965 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 965 KB

* installing *source* package ‘xgboost’ ...
** package ‘xgboost’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking Backtrace lib...
checking for backtrace in -lexecinfo... no
checking endian...
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
Makevars:17: -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1
Makevars:17: -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0
Makevars:17: -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=1
Makevars:17: -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1
Makevars:17: -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1
Makevars:17: -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1
Makevars:17: -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_
g++ -std=c++11  -I"/opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=1 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_  -I/usr/local/include -fopenmp -DDMLC_CMAKE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -pthread   -O3 -mtune = native -march = native -fPIC -c xgboost_R.cc -o xgboost_R.o
g++: error: =: No such file or directory
g++: error: native: No such file or directory
g++: error: =: No such file or directory
g++: error: native: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mtune’; did you mean ‘-mtune=’?
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-march’; did you mean ‘-march=’?
make: *** [/opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:173: xgboost_R.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xgboost’
* removing ‘/opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/library/xgboost’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmp0uG7uW/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("xgboost") :
  installation of package ‘xgboost’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with the command you are running and the version of R you are using?

Comment: @jakub I’m running install.packages(“xgboost”) in R 3.6.3 on centos  7

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the arguments to `g++` have spaces, like `-mtune = native -march = native`. Unfortunately I don't know what would cause that...

Comment: Anybody has any luck here will be appreciated. i am still unable to solve this